# cell border expand beyond

Tags: css, cell, curve

In below html/css code left borders of the first two cells are used as range brackets. Is it possible to make the borders appear as shown in the below screenshot?

[image]

```css
.Row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}

.Column {
  display: table-cell;
  border-style: solid;
}

.Column:nth-child(1) {
  width:20%;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;  
}
.Column:nth-child(2) {
  width:50%;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.Column:nth-child(3) {
  width:30%;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column"></div>
  <div class="Column">Accepted Range</div>
  <div class="Column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @LGSon sorry but Iaconis Simone's answer is more suitable in my case.

Comment: No problem, just wanted you to chose an answer that best solved your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use

```
border-radius: 7px;
```

hide right border in central column and show left border in the right one

```css
.Row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}

.Column {
  display: table-cell;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 7px;
}

.Column:nth-child(1) {
  width:20%;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;  
}
.Column:nth-child(2) {
  width:50%;
  border-left: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right:none;
  text-align: center;
}
.Column:nth-child(3) {
  width:30%;
  border-right: none;
  border-top: none;
  border-bottom: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column"></div>
  <div class="Column">Accepted Range</div>
  <div class="Column"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Just to clarify I cannot exchange the borders for this purpose as I have specific use case where only specific borders can be used as mentioned in the question. But your suggestion of using border-radius will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

You could use pseudo elements to do that, and since they use a character, you can easily change and also color them with `color` along with any range text you need.

Also, with this solution, you will be able to use the borders for what they are ment to be used.

```css
.Row {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-spacing: 5px;
}

.Column {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
}

.Column:nth-child(1) {
  width:20%;
}
.Column:nth-child(2) {
  width:50%;
  text-align: center;
}
.Column:nth-child(3) {
  width:30%;
}
.Column:nth-child(1)::before,
.Column:nth-child(3)::before {
  content: '❳';
  left: 100%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 24px;
  position: absolute;
}
.Column:nth-child(3)::before {
  content: '❲';
  left: auto;
  right: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="Row">
  <div class="Column"></div>
  <div class="Column">Accepted Range</div>
  <div class="Column"></div>
</div>
```